# Understanding cascading deletes in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, cascading-deletes

I've put together a very simple 1:many relationship where the parent is nullable. The design of the system is that each Event has exactly 1 parent, any of County, State, or Campaign.

An event should never have all three set to null nor should it have more than one set to a non-null value.

When a County/State/Campaign is deleted, it's child Events need to be deleted.

```
    public class Campaign
    {
        public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
        // lots of other properties...
    }
    
    public class Event
    {
        public County? County { get; set; }
        public State? State { get; set; }
        public Campaign? Campaign { get; set; }
        // lots of other properties...
    }
```

So first on the cascading delete. I built the DB with the following Configuration. I tried it three ways where it:

1. Did not have the OnDelete() call
2. Called OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)
3. OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)

```
    public class CampaignConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Campaign>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Campaign> builder)
        {
            builder.HasMany(x => x.Events)
                .WithOne(x => x.Campaign).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
        }
    }
```

The only difference in the migration files was InitialCreate.cs. InitialCreate.Designer.cs & CreateModelSnapshot.cs have a difference where it repeats what was set in the Configure, but I assume that is not what EF determined to do but rather just a recording of what was written in my code.

nothing & ClientCascade:

```
           constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Events", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Events_Campaigns_CampaignId",
                    column: x => x.CampaignId,
                    principalTable: "Campaigns",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
```

Cascade:

```
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Events", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Events_Campaigns_CampaignId",
                    column: x => x.CampaignId,
                    principalTable: "Campaigns",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

Which leads to three questions:

1. In the nothing case the Event.CampaignId is set to null. That is the correct action for a nullable parent, but why/how does that happen?
2. In the case of ClientCascade, the event objects are deleted even though onDelete was not set - why/how does that happen?
3. And a fundamental puzzlement, the mitigation files are the same for nothing and ClientCascade yet it's different behavior. Where does that difference come from? Is it the InitialCreate.Designer.cs or CreateModelSnapshot.cs differences? Do those also get fed to the underlying database?

And maybe relevant - according to [Cascade Delete - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#impact-on-database-schema) the ClientCascade will throw a DbUpdateException on an *Optional relationship with dependents/children not loaded* when you delete the parent. So probably good to stay away from it.

Comment: ClientCascade tells EF to perform the cascade delete regardless of what the DB might be set to. This means that if you load an entity and delete it, any currently tracked relatives set to ClientCascade will be deleted. The "currently tracked" is significant because this means to reliably ensure that these relatives are cascade deleted you need to eager load them. A DbContext may already be tracking all or maybe just some of those relatives which would see those ones deleted, but any remaining would either be Nulled or result in a FK violation depending on DB behaviour.

Comment: @StevePy Is it correct to say that ClientCascade will cause EF to enforce the cascading delete, but only for Properties in the object due to an Include()?  
While Cascade will leave it to the DB to enforce cascading delete, which will perform a full cascading delete regardless of what Include() calls were/not made, but only if the DB is capable of that?  
If so, then it's Cascade for a DB that can enforce (like SQL Server) and ClientCascade for a DB that does not?

Comment: Generally, yes, but not always. Say a Customer has 3 orders. Within the scope of a DbContext you load Order #1, then within the same DbContext lifetime load the Customer with intention to delete it. You don't `Include` customer.Orders, however EF is tracking Order #1 so it will automatically be added to customer.Orders. (Order #2 and #3 will not) A ClientCascade would delete Order #1 in this case, but #2 and #3 would be left orphaned. So if relying on ClientCascade you absolutely will need to remember to use `Include` to eager load, or you could have inconsistent results.

Comment: This behaviour with tracked references being linked can lead to various issues that are situational, where everything works fine in some scenarios merely because those scenarios resulted in the related entities being available despite not being eager loaded. That could be a complete set or a partial set. It can result at runtime to be an intermittent or seemingly unpredictable issue. (Affecting what is loaded, what is updated, or what is cascade deleted) Your "A or B or C" reference scenario pretty much requires client cascade or explicit deletion.

Comment: @StevePy Thank you. I'm divining in to my A or B or C next. But for the simpler 1:many, I'm going to use Cascade as my underlying DB is SQL Server. It's too easy to forget a needed Include() plus it's pulling in a lot of unnecessary data if I go the ClientCascade approach. Again, thanks for your help. And if you want to throw your comments together into an answer, I'm happy to select it.